# getting the proper date format in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to fetch the Start date and end date from the following date format

```
Wed 19 - Sat 22 June 2013
```

Now what i want the output is :-

```
Startdate = 2013-06-19
Enddate = 2013-06-22
```

But i am getting the output as:-

```
Startdate = 1970-01-01
Enddate = 2013-06-22
```

What i have tried:-

```
$old_date = explode('-',$date);
$startdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($old_date[0]));
$enddate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($old_date[1]));
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Startdate is not exploded properly. After exploding with '-', June 2013 should be added. thats the problem

Comment: How can we add that ?? Any suggestions ???

Comment: What happens if the date range crosses a month boundary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
$date= "Wed 19 - Sat 22 June 2013";
$old_date = explode(' - ',$date);
$Xdate=explode(" ",$old_date[1]);
$startdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($old_date[0]." ".$Xdate[2]." ".$Xdate[3]));
$enddate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($old_date[1]));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$date = "Wed 19 - Sat 22 June 2013";
$old_date = explode('-',$date);
$date = explode(' ', trim($old_date[1])); //updated line 
$startdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($old_date[0].' '.$date[2].' '.$date[3]));
$enddate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($old_date[1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to split both parts of your date string.

```
$date= "Wed 19 - Sat 22 June 2013";

//split dates into array
$dates_array = explode(' - ',$date);

//get end date which is complete
list($EndDate, $Year) = explode(',', date('Y-m-d,Y', strtotime($dates_array[1])));

//Build start date
$StartDateStr = $dates_array[0] . $Year;

//Convert
$StartDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($StartDateStr));

echo "StartDate = $StartDate";
echo "EndDate = $EndDate";
```

Hope that's useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this in many ways. Here's one way of doing it.

```
<?php
$date = 'Wed 19 - Sat 22 June 2013';
$old_date = explode(' ',$date);

$year = $old_date[6];  
$month = $old_date[5];
$firstDay = $old_date[1];
$secondDay = $old_date[4];
$yearAndMonth = $year . '-' . date('m', strtotime($month)) . '-';

$startDate = $yearAndMonth . $firstDay;
$endDate = $yearAndMonth . $secondDay;
echo $startDate . '<br />' . $endDate;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
2013-06-19
2013-06-22
```

I believe this example gives rather good readabiliy. It would not work though if you add something to the `$date`-string, like `$date = 'Wed 19 2013 - Sat 22 June 2013';`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$sDateString = 'Wed 19 - Sat 22 June 2013';

$sStartDay = preg_replace("/^([a-zA-Z]{3,4} [0-9]{2}).+/", "$1", $sDateString);
$sEndDay = preg_replace("/.+ \- ([a-zA-Z]{3,4} [0-9]{2}).+/", "$1", $sDateString);
$sMonth = preg_replace("/.+ ([a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]{4})$/", "$1", $sDateString);

$sStartDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($sStartDay . ' ' . $sMonth));
$sEndDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($sEndDay . ' ' . $sMonth));

echo("<p>" . $sStartDate . "</p>");
echo("<p>" . $sEndDate . "</p>");
```

Output:

```
2013-06-19
2013-06-22
```